# Building a Dotnet api docker image with a base image of class libraries

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create an API microservice that utilises a shared library of models. When creating the image, i require to have these classes within scope. However, due to the structure of my project, these models are not always within scope.
I decided to create a base image with these universally used models, and build my apis on top of these images. However, i encounter an issue regarding what i believe is a problem with the structure that i just can't seem to wrap my head around.

When building i receive the error mentioned below. If I manually reference where these libraries are i usually have no issues, however i need them to be within a reusable image for ease.

The following is the two dockerfiles, as well as an example of how my project is structured, as well as where the api expects to import the class libary from when being build. Any idea on what i am doing wrong?

**API dockerfile**

```
    FROM base-image AS base
    WORKDIR /App
    EXPOSE 80
    
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
    WORKDIR /src
    
    
    COPY ["Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj", "Services/Audit/Audit.API/"]
    COPY --from=base /src/EventBus.Messages/ /src/Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/
    
    RUN dotnet restore "./Services/Audit/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj" --source http://address
    COPY . .
    WORKDIR "/src/Services/Audit/Audit.API"
    RUN dotnet build "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/build
    
    FROM build AS publish
    RUN dotnet publish "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
    
    FROM base AS final
    WORKDIR /App
    COPY --from=publish /App/publish .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Audit.API.dll"]
```

**Base Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Responses/Responses/Responses.csproj", "Responses/"]
COPY ["EventBus.Messages/EventBus.Messages.csproj", "EventBus.Messages/"]
```

**Error**

```
 => ERROR [build 8/8] RUN dotnet build "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/build                                                                4.0s
------
 > [build 8/8] RUN dotnet build "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/build:
#0 0.804 MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
#0 1.258   Determining projects to restore...
#0 1.748   Restored /src/Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/EventBus.Messages.csproj (in 119 ms).
#0 1.922   Restored /src/Services/Audit/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj (in 310 ms).
#0 3.443   EventBus.Messages -> /App/build/EventBus.Messages.dll
#0 3.904 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Services/Audit/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj]
#0 3.912
#0 3.912 Build FAILED.
#0 3.912
#0 3.912 CSC : error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/Services/Audit/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj]
#0 3.912     0 Warning(s)
#0 3.912     1 Error(s)
#0 3.912
#0 3.912 Time Elapsed 00:00:03.01
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c dotnet build "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/build]: exit code: 1
```

**AUDIT.API package reference**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Building-Blocks\EventBus.Messages\EventBus.Messages.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Folder structure**

```
Building-Blocks
 EventBus.Messages
Services
 Audit
  Audit.API
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to copy the source code on the base image.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Responses/Responses/", "Responses/"]
COPY ["EventBus.Messages/", "EventBus.Messages/"]
```

I suppose the problem you have with building a single image is due to the position where you launch the `docker build` command.

You can execute `docker build` starting from the root folder and specify the Dockerfile with the `-f` parameter, in this case, the path you set on Dockerfile referring to the root folder.

You can save Dockerfile whatever path you want, the important note is to remember that the path inside Dockefile is referred to the path where you launch the build command or how you change/specify the path on command, usually the dot (docker build -t xxx -f Dockerfile .) the final dot is the folder referred then on Dockerfile.

With Dockerfile on the root path.

Building-Blocks
--EventBus.Messages
Services
--Audit
----Audit.API
Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-focal AS build

WORKDIR /src
# Copy the .csproj for restore
COPY ["Building-Blocks/Responses/Responses/Responses.csproj", "Building-Blocks/Responses/"]
COPY ["Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/EventBus.Messages.csproj", "Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/"]
COPY ["Services/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj", "Services/Audit/Audit.API/"]
    
# Restore the main project 
RUN dotnet restore "./Services/Audit/Audit.API/Audit.API.csproj" --source http://address
    
COPY ["Building-Blocks/Responses/Responses/", "Building-Blocks/Responses/"]
COPY ["Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/", "Building-Blocks/EventBus.Messages/"]
COPY ["Services/Audit.API/", "Services/Audit/Audit.API/"]

WORKDIR "/src/Services/Audit/Audit.API"

# --no-restore, you already have a restore stage above
RUN dotnet build "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release --no-restore -o /App/build
    
# Get the runtime only you don't need the SDK to run the image
RUN dotnet publish "Audit.API.csproj" -c Release -o /App/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
    
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0-focal AS pub
WORKDIR /App
COPY --from=build /App/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Audit.API.dll"]
```

Add these entries to the `.dockerignore` file

```
**/bin
**/obj
**/.vscode
**/.vs
```

Otherwise the build with `--no-restore` fail because on the `COPY` phase it copy also the `bin&obj` folders with (maybe) different assemblies, if you develop on windows and build on linux image.

Then you can run the build command from root `docker build -t whatever -f Dockerfile .`